# How can I show different image links for different languages with qTranslate?

Tags: links, multi-language

I have a set of links, each with an image - how can I show different links depending on the language selected (using qTranslate) - the images have text on them..

At the moment I show these links using the rotating links widget.

Are there any plugins to help with this? or do I need to resort to PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current language with qtranslate using the function `qtrans_getLanguage()`; and then use it like this for conditionally showing content:

```
    <?php  
        if ( qtrans_getLanguage() == 'en' ) {
          //put your code in here
        }
        elseif ( qtrans_getLanguage() == 'de' ) {
          //put your code in here
        }
    ?>
```